# Change text color add field in android contact app

Tags: android, field, addition, contacts, textcolor

I'm theming LG ICS contacts app by editing XML, but I can't change the text color of list items when I try to add a new field. Event, web site, nickname, IM, Notes are in black, and I want these in white.